# why it show me this in result (list index out of range)?

Tags: python-3.x

Write a function called stop_at_z that iterates through a list of strings. Using a while loop, append each string to a new list until the string that appears is “z”. The function should return the new list.

```
def stop_at_z(str):
    d = 0 
    x=[]
    str1 = list(str)
    while True : 
        if str1[d] != 'Z' :            
            x.append(str1[d])
            d+=1
        if str1[d] == 'Z' :
            break 
    return x
```

Using a while loop, append each string to a new list until the string that appears is “z”. The function should return the new list.

Comment: Have you wondered what would happen if the string 'z' is not actually part of the list of strings?

Comment: Also, `str` is the name of the string class in Python. You shouldn't use it as a variable name.

Comment: And one more thing, you need to check if the string is lowercase 'z' or not too for completeness

Comment: i tried changing name of parameter and check if the string contains lowercase 'z' and it doesn't work

Comment: You should check for both capital and lowercase. And stay within the size of the list. And return something like -1 if the list didn't contain z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the the way you are doing it, searching for “z” is case-sensitive, try something like:

```
If str1[d].strip().lower() == “z”
```

It strips off leading and trailing white space and then converts the str1 element to lower case (both of these simply return the modified string, so the original is unchanged) and compares it to a lower case z

Comment: the problem specified small  'z'

Comment: In the code you posted, it looks like you’re comparing it to a big “Z”. Also, look at the code in glhr’s answer for a good look at how to handle the case of “z” not appearing (just in case)

Comment: Note that `str1[d].strip().lower() == "z"` will match both lowercase and uppercase `z`.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because `d` keeps increasing infinitely if there is no uppercase 'Z' in the string. Instead, you should only stay in the `while` loop while the full length of the input string has not been reached:

```
def stop_at_z(inputstr):
    d = 0 
    x=[]
    str1 = list(inputstr)
    while d<len(inputstr) :      
        if str1[d] == 'z' :
            break 
        else:           
            x.append(str1[d])
            d+=1
    return x
```

Note that you can achieve the same thing using [`takewhile()` from the `itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
from itertools import takewhile

def stop_at_z(inputstr):
    return list(takewhile(lambda i: i != 'z', inputstr))

print(stop_at_z("hello wzrld"))
```

Output:

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w']
```

Answer (score 0):

What if the string 'z' is never in the list? 

Then it keeps on increasing the index and eventually runs into an error.

Answer (score 0):

Just restricting the loop to the length of the list should help.

```
def stop_at_z(str):
    d = 0 
    x=[]
    str1 = list(str)
    for d in range(0,len(str1)) : 
        print(d)
        if str1[d] != 'Z' :            
            x.append(str1[d])
        else:
            break 
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we needed to have a list that could have all the characters until we get "z". One way we could do that is we first convert the string into a list and iterate that list and add every character to a new list `ls` until we get "z". But the problem is we may get a string that doesn't have "z" so we need to iterate till the length of that list. I hope it is clear.

```
def stop_at_z(s):
    ls = []
    idx = 0
    x = list(s)
    while idx<len(x):
        if x[idx]=="z":
            break
        ls.append(x[idx])
        idx+=1
    return ls
```

Comment: explain more :)

Answer (score 0):

It's my first time posting here, but I use this while loop:

```
def stop_at_z(input_list):
    print (input_list)
    output_list=[]
    index=0
    while index< len(input_list):
        if input_list[index] != "z":
            output_list.append(input_list[index])
            index+=1
        else:
            break
    return output_list
```